# Entity Framework Posting records

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I've got this model:

```
public class FinalizedWebinarAttendeesList
{
    public List<FinalizedWebinar> Webinars { get; set; }
}

public class FinalizedWebinar
{
    public int ParticipantID { get; set; }
    public bool AffidavitRecvd { get; set; }
    public string EventCode { get; set; }
}
```

And this DbContext:

```
public class webinarFinalizedAttendeesListDbContext : DbContext
{
    public webinarFinalizedAttendeesListDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString) { }
    public DbSet<FinalizedWebinar> WebinarFinalAttendee { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to send the entire FinalizedWebinarAttendeesList to a function vs. having to send each of them (like below).
Is this possible?

```
public void InsertAttendee(FinalizedWebinar aa)
{
    using (webinarFinalizedAttendeesListDbContext context = new webinarFinalizedAttendeesListDbContext(connectionString))
    {
        context.WebinarFinalAttendee.Add(aa);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DbSet<T>` has an `.AddRange(IEnumerable<T>)` method that you can use:

```
context.WebinarFinalAttendee.AddRange(attendees);
```

More info at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.addrange(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: I really wanted to send the entire list to a procedure in my Oracle DB and have it loop through them to insert vs. using the DbContext to add them. Is that possible? I'll still have to write my Oracle procedure, if I can.

Comment: If you're already using Entity Framework for this, I'm uncertain what you're hoping to achieve by doing the insert directly in Oracle.  Entity Framework will take care of that for you.

Comment: Because the records really do not correspond to the data that needs to be inserted. That is why I am having to write an Oracle stored procedure to do the actual inserts.  `I'd like to send the entire FinalizedWebinarAttendeesList to a function vs. having to send each of them (like below). `

Comment: If it were me, I would look at reshaping the data in C# such that it's ready to be put right into the database.  To do things the way you're asking instead, you may want to look up array binding in ODP.NET, which has nothing to do with Entity Framework.

Comment: I'm rewriting all of my stuff to use Petapoco as it is a lot easier to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, why not ? Adapt this example to better fit your needs :

```
public void InsertAttendee(List<FinalizedWebinar> webinars)
{
    using (webinarFinalizedAttendeesListDbContext context = new webinarFinalizedAttendeesListDbContext(connectionString))
    {
        foreach(var webinar in webinars) {
            context.WebinarFinalAttendee.Add(webinar);
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

A context in Entity Framework will remember all changes to tracked objects and apply them all at once when saved. You can perform as many operations as you wish inside the context.

Note: pushing this to the extreme will likely have an undesirable performance impact, but as long as you're doing a reasonable amount of work, everything should be fine. As always, measure for performance impacts if you're worried there's a problem.

Comment: That also has to loop through the list to add them all. I wanted to not have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like [DbSet.AddRange()](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/addrange-removerange.aspx)? You can add items to an IEnumerable and add the IEnumerable to your DbSet.